# Multiple Calculations in case statement not running

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, case-when

I am trying to run a query that obtains an average for two different variables then calculates the difference between them. However, the I keep getting an error that the query doesn't recognize the variable names in the second calculation. I have been looking around but I feel like I am just missing a simple step here

Here is the full query

```
select 
DATEPART(dw,t1.Date),
DATENAME(dw,t1.Date),
AVG (CASE WHEN (rraw.Mode='Passive') THEN  T1.LengthSec + T1.Sec ELSE NULL
END) AS 'Passive',
AVG (CASE WHEN (rraw.Mode='Active') THEN  T1.Sec + T1.Sec ELSE NULL
END) AS 'Active'
then ( Passive - Active ) / Passive * 100.0 AS 'ModePrctDiff'
from bm.t1agent t1 with (nolock)
JOIN prc.Request rreq
on t1.id = rreq.t1ID
join PRC.Raw rraw with (nolock) 
on rreq.ID = rraw.Id
where t1.Date >= '2014-12-07'
GROUP BY  ROLLUP ((DATEPART(dw,t1.Date),DATENAME(dw,t1.Date)))
```

The error is occurring on the then statement. If I run it without that part, I obtain these results

```
 Day Of Week    Passive       Active
 Sunday         350.54        370.54
 Monday         365.54        380.91
```

I want to have the results read

```
Day Of Week    Passive       Active  Difference
Sunday         350.54        370.54   xxxx
Monday         365.54        380.91   xxxx
```

Comment: What does the third "THEN" belong to?   There's no CASE statement associated with it.

Comment: @TabAlleman
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'then'.


I only get this error when I add the 'THEN' statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't use the `alias name` given to a column in the same `select` clause

you need to write it as a subquery or cte.

```
with cte 
as 
(
    select 
    DATEPART(dw,t1.Date) as dw1,
    DATENAME(dw,t1.Date) as dw2,
    AVG (CASE WHEN (rraw.Mode='Passive') THEN  T1.LengthSec + T1.Sec ELSE NULL
    END) AS 'Passive',
    AVG (CASE WHEN (rraw.Mode='Active') THEN  T1.Sec + T1.Sec ELSE NULL
    END) AS 'Active'
    from bm.t1agent t1 with (nolock)
    JOIN prc.Request rreq
    on t1.id = rreq.t1ID
    join PRC.Raw rraw with (nolock) 
    on rreq.ID = rraw.Id
    where t1.Date >= '2014-12-07'
    GROUP BY  ROLLUP ((DATEPART(dw,t1.Date),DATENAME(dw,t1.Date))) 
)
select * , ( Passive - Active ) / Passive * 100.0 AS 'ModePrctDiff'
from cte
```

Comment: this appears correct but when I run it I get this error:

No column name was specified for column 1 of 'cte'

Comment: @user3120266, give column in the select , i gave it as dw1, dw2